# Resetting the .off() method

Tags: jquery

I am had a function that fired again in the function. So i thought i use the `.off()` to prevent that and then at the end i want to reinstate the event listeners again. But no idea how that would work. Here is my code.

```
$('#modal_add_season_season_price').on('input keyup paste change', function() {
  $(this).off('input keyup paste change')
  console.log("1")
  $("#modal_add_season_price_warning").hide()
  var c = this.selectionStart,
    r = <?php echo $seperator=="," ? "/[^0-9,]/" : "/[^0-9.]/" ?>,
    v = $(this).val(),
    z = false;
  i = 0;
  while (r.test(v) && i < 10) {
    z = true;
    v = v.replace(r, '');
    c--;
    i++
  }
  if (z) {
    $("#modal_add_season_price_warning").show()
    $("#modal_add_season_price_warning").find('small').html("<i class=fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Only numbers are allowed here. Decimal seperator is a <?php echo $seperator=="," ? "',' (comma)" : "'.' (dot)"; ?>")
    $(this).val(v)
  }
  this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
  if ($.isNumeric($(this).val()) && z == false) {
    console.log(z)
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_valuta").addClass('is-valid')
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_valuta").removeClass('is-invalid')
    $(this).addClass('is-valid')
    $(this).removeClass('is-invalid')
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_span").addClass('is-valid')
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_span").removeClass('is-invalid')
  }
  else {
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_valuta").addClass('is-invalid')
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_valuta").removeClass('is-valid')
    $(this).addClass('is-invalid')
    $(this).removeClass('is-valid')
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_span").addClass('is-invalid')
    $(".modal_add_season_season_price_span").removeClass('is-valid')
  }
});
```

So I noticed something strange and with the `console.log` i saw that it fired twice. I added the `.off()` and now it fired only once like i wanted. However now i have the problem that it does not listen to new inputs anymore on this input. I tried googling it but to no avail. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Bind each element only once then you don't need the `off`. Use the three-parameters form `$(document.body).on('click', '.class',function(){});`

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I have this element only bound once. And how does it help to move the listener to the body instead of on the element itself? The problem is that i change the element again in the function so thats why it triggers again

Comment: You are binding many events on ```#modal_add_season_season_price```, try with ```input ``` only

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to stop repetitions caused by changing the element:

```
var inside_price = false;
$(document.body).on('input keyup paste change', '#modal_add_season_season_price', function() {
    if(inside_price) return;
    inside_price = true;
    ...
    inside_price = false;
}
```

The three parameter form of `on` also triggers for elements added dynamically.